# Mongoose reverse lookup and delete

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reference

I am trying to make a healthcheck on references in one of my `collections`. so to see if objects referenced to still exist and if not I want to delete that `_id` in the `array`

I haven't found anything to that so my idea is to get the `reversed` result of a `$lookup`

Is it possible to get the reversed result of a lookup in MongoDB?

Here is an example of a collection and its `taskList` with references to the `tasks` collection.
[image]

Now I want to delete all the id's in there that do not have an existing result in the `tasks` collection.

How I solve it right now which is tons of queries:

1. get all the ids from `taskList`
2. Send a query for every single one of them to see if there is no match with the task collection
3. Send a query to pull that empty reference out of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want, its ok even if you have big collections.

But its not an update you can do after that a `$merge` stage, to the tasklists (if match on _id replace)(requires MongoDB >= 4.4) or you can do a `$out` stage to another collection, and replace the tasklist collection.

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d9W9V55cA0p)

Data in

```js
db={
  "tasklists": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "tasklist": [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "tasklist": [
        5,
        6,
        7
      ]
    }
  ],
  "tasks": [
    {
      "_id": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": 2
    },
    {
      "_id": 3
    },
    {
      "_id": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

```js
db.tasklists.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "tasks",
      "let": {
        "tasklist": "$tasklist"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$in": [
                "$_id",
                "$$tasklist"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "valid"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "valid": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$valid",
          "as": "v",
          "in": "$$v._id"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "tasklist": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$tasklist",
          "as": "t",
          "cond": {
            "$in": [
              "$$t",
              "$valid"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": [
      "valid"
    ]
  }
])
```

Results (tasks 4,6,7 wasnt found in the task collection,and removed)

```js
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "tasklist": [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "tasklist": [
      5
    ]
  }
]
```

---

**Edit**

If you want to use index to do the `$lookup` you can try this

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YARKIGfVubZ)

Tasks have index on `_id` so no need to make one, if you dont join on `_id` make one.

```js
db.tasklists.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$tasklist"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "tasks",
      "localField": "tasklist",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "joined"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$gt": [
          {
            "$size": "$joined"
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": [
      "joined"
    ]
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "tasklist": {
        "$push": "$tasklist"
      },
      "afield": {
        "$first": "$afield"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

After that you can do `$out` or `$merge` with replace option.
But both lose the updated data if any while this was happening.

Only solution for this(if it is a problem) `$merge` with pipeline,
You need to keep also in the pipeline above an extra array with the initial tasklist, so you remove the valid ones, to have the invalid ones, and then on merge with pipeline to filter the array, and just removed those invalid. (this is safe, from data loss)

I think the best approach instead of doing all those is to have an index on tasklist(multikey index) and when an _id is deleted from tasks,to delete the _id from the array in tasklist.With index it will be fast, so you dont need to check for invalid _ids.

Comment: This surprisingly worked wonders thank you very much,
though I do not quite understand how it works with the double '$'  but it works ;)

Comment: its mongoDB variable, its like normal variable its just a name on a value, i dont know if it can be done in a simpler way.

Comment: Ok so unfortunately this isn't quite fast since it is a lot of writing to and with my 1M+ datasets it takes roughly 3 seconds.
If i do some minor logic with 3 seperate queries as I mentioned I run it in less time.
Additionally this doesn't actually overwrite any of the data nor does it filter out those taskLists that are fine.
It only returns the documents at the end of the pipeline and I still would have to overwrite the actual documents with the new document taskLists adding even more time.

Comment: i tried, see edit, update doesn't allow us to use `$lookup` so only way is `$merge` or `$out` i think, with the edit you can use index on the lookup, but you do an extra group, its expected to be faster

Answer (score 1):

Afaik there's no other way than you described in order to achieve the desired outcome, but you can greatly simplify the second step to find the non-matching items. In fact it's the set difference between the `taskList`-ids and the existing `task`-ids.

So you could use the `$setDifference`-[operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) to calculate that difference:

```
db.tasks.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "null",
      ids: {
        "$addToSet": "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      nonMatchingTaskIds: {
        $setDifference: [
          [
            "taskId1",
            "taskId2",
            "taskId7",
            "taskId8"
          ],
          "$ids"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Assuming your `tasks` collection contains `taskId1`, `task2` (and other documents), but not `taskId7` and `taskId8`, the query will result in `nonMatchingTaskIds` containing `taskId7` and `taskId8`.

Here's an example on mongoplayground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/75BpiGBJi3Q

Comment: yes the setDifference is exactly what i was looking for in terms of a reversed lookup ty.
But this requires me to load in the array of taskIds in a total. and since I have 1M+ Data idk if an array is made for that amount, but if that is no problem I am so down to use this.

Answer (score 0):

So what I came to do now is a few stepped method.
This is quite fast but sicne the taskIds collected from Sets are currently way smaller than the entire amount of sets I imagine working with the `$setDifference` operator mentioned by eol will be faster once I get that many references.

```js
let taskIdsInSets = []
    // Get all referenced task ids
    const result = await this.setSchema.aggregate([
      {
        '$project': {
          'taskList': 1
        }
      }
    ])

    // Map all elements in one row
    result.forEach(set => taskIdsInSets.push(...set.taskList.map(x=> x.toString())))

    // Delete duplicates of taskIds here
    taskIdsInSets.filter((item, index) => taskIdsInSets.indexOf(item) != index)

    // Get the existing task ids that are referenced in a Set
    const result2 = await this.taskSchema.aggregate([
      {
        '$match': {
          '_id': {
            '$in': [...taskIdsInSets.map(x => Types.ObjectId(x.toString()))]
          }
        }
      }, {
        '$project': {
          '_id': 1
        }
      }
    ])

    let existingIdsInTasks = []
    // Getting ids from result2 Object into
    result2.forEach(set => existingIdsInTasks.push(set._id.toString()))

    // Filtering out the ids that don't actually exist
    let nonExistingTaskIds = taskIdsInSets.filter(x => existingIdsInTasks.indexOf(x) === -1);

    // Deleting the ids that don't actually exist but are in Sets
    const finalResult = await this.setSchema.updateMany(
      {
        $pullAll: {
          taskList: [...nonExistingTaskIds.map(x => Types.ObjectId(x.toString()))]
        }
      })
    console.log(finalResult)
    return finalResult // returns the information how much got changed. unfortunately in mongoose there isn't the option to use findAndModify with `{new:true}` or atleast I didn't manage to make it work.
```

for some reason what the database returns neither matches the Mongo ObjectId nor strings so I have to do some castings there.